# python request with cookie from pickle string?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am submitting requests to an API that can often take several hours for my requests to complete and return data.  I am working on writing a python solution where my script will submit the requests and write the status info to a file on my laptop that can be retrieved later if needed.

When I submit a job to the API, the API responds with a status URL that can be used to check the status of my job.  However, due to the site's load balancing, I also need to retrieve the session cookie from my initial request and use that cookie to ensure I hit the right server when I am using the returned status URL to check my job status.

I am able to retrieve the status URL from the API as well as the cookie from the request using this code.  Note that I often submit multiple jobs, so there may be multiple status URL's/cookies in the file:

```
# Submit the request to the API
rPOST = requests.post(url, auth=(uname, passwd), data=json_data, headers=headers)
CookieMonster = pickle.dumps(rPOST.cookies) # Get the cookie as a string

# Grab the JSON data currently in the file:
with open(statFile, mode='r') as status_json:
    StatusDict = json.load(status_json)
    status_json.close()
# Add new URL and cookie to the JSON and write back to the file:
with open(statFile, mode='w') as status_json:
    StatusDict[(str(json.loads(rPOST.text)[u'link'][u'href']))] = CookieMonster
    json.dump(StatusDict, status_json)
    status_json.close()
```

The submit code works fine, but I am getting a 404 error when trying to check the job status using the status URL

```
# Grab the JSON data currently in the file:    
with open(statFile, mode='r') as status_json:
    StatusDict = json.load(status_json)
    status_json.close()  

# Check each URL and see if my job's are done:
for url in StatusDict:
    CookieMonster = pickle.loads(StatusDict[url])
    rGET = requests.get(url, auth=(uname, passwd), cookies=CookieMonster)
```

The JSON in my status file looks like this:

```
{
    "https://example.com/sfsalk242234": "Pickled cookie string data here",
    "https://example.com/sfsa34532234": "Pickled cookie string data here",
    "https://example.com/23423fsdfssd": "Pickled cookie string data here"
}
```

This has something to do with the cookies=CookieMonster parameter.  If I remove the cookies parameter, and just fire off the code a bunch of times, I'll eventually get load balanced to the correct server and get a response.  However when I am using the cookies parameter I never get a response and always get a HTTP 404 message.

Also note that for jobs that run a very long time, I often need to disconnect my laptop, sleep, reboot, etc... so keeping the script running to preserve the original cookie object isn't really a viable option, which is why I'm writing the status URL's and cookie data to disk.

How do I properly store a cookie like this and then retrieve it for use in a future request?

**Updated Solution**

```
rPOST = requests.post(url, auth=(uname, passwd), data=json_data, headers=headers)
CookieMonster = rPOST.cookies
with open(statFile, mode='w') as status_json:
    StatusDict[(str(json.loads(rPOST.text)[u'link'][u'href']))] = CookieMonster.items()
    json.dump(StatusDict, status_json)
```

Then change the retrieval to look like this:

```
# Check each URL and see if my job's are done:
for url, cookies in StatusDict:
    rGET = requests.get(url, auth=(uname, passwd), cookies=dict(cookies))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using pickle as the RequestsCookieJar is somewhat of a wrapper around a dictionary, and requests methods take dictionaries as input for cookies.

```
with open(statFile, mode='w') as status_json:
    StatusDict[(str(json.loads(rPOST.text)[u'link'][u'href']))] = CookieMonster.items()
    json.dump(StatusDict, status_json)
```

Then later

```
# Check each URL and see if my job's are done:
for url, cookies in StatusDict:
    rGET = requests.get(url, auth=(uname, passwd), cookies=dict(cookies))
```

Comment: Thank you!  The one thing I would add to your code though, is that CookieMonster = pickle.dumps(rPOST.cookies) needs to be changed to CookieMonster = rPOST.cookies to work.  With that one update it worked like a charm!